# How to find the location of a SKNode inside another SKNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a simple project where the user flies a spaceship around a world and blasts stuff. Nothing fancy. I'm having a real problem though with the actual firing of the projectile. I'm able to create a projectile (`laser`) at the ship's location (`player.position`) within the world, rotate it, and fire it off in the direction of the ship. The problem is that I want it to fire off IN FRONT of the ship (I'm writing it in *Swift* btw). When I do the following

```
//this starts the laser 2 units in front of the ship.
laser.position.y = player.position.y + 27 
laser.position.x = player.position.x
```

the laser will stay permanently above the ship regardless of what angle the ship is currently rotated to (no surprise). So I created a small SKShapeNode `fireingPosition` to sit inside the `player` node and rotate with the ship. Now, although I'm able to get this working, I can't figure out a way to find this node's position within the world, as `fireingPosition.position` only returns the location of the shape WITHIN the player node.

If you're a little lost, here's kindof an overview of the hierarchy tree.

WorldNode -> PlayerNode (the spaceship) -> fireingPosition (the small shape)

Basically, what is the best way to find the position of the fireingPosition node inside of the WorldNode.

Comment: Check out the converting system from `SKNodes` https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/convertPoint:fromNode:

Comment: @Kendel Thank you Kendel.